# JPasswordField returning some hash code converted into string type

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

My program takes user name and password authentication from user before initialising the program,
so i created a button login to which i associated ActionListener as show below

```
   login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                if(txtUserName.getText().equals("Suraj") && (txtPwd.getPassword().toString()).equals("s123")){

                                dispose();
                                TimeFrame tFrame = new TimeFrame(userName);
                                tFrame.setVisible(true);
                                tFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                                tFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout());

                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User name or password don't match","Acces Denied", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
```

Now the problem that occurs is even if i enter correct password, program displays an error mes[image]sage

Comment: any issue, no idea what9s hidden in the rest of your code, work for me, maybe better way would be read [getText() vs getPassword()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798066/gettext-vs-getpassword)

Comment: @mKorbel +1 for the link to the question which explains it all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getPassword()` returns a `char[]`. The `toString()` on it does not return the contents as a string as you assume.

Try `new String(txtPwd.getPassword()).equals("s123")`.

However, there is a reason it is a `char[]` and not a String. Try looking up the security aspect of it in [the javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29)

Comment: +1, for using `new String(...)`, I thought you missed it, so posted my answer, now deleted it, after reading that one line :-)

Comment: i had read that you can convert int into string and char into string by using the respective toString() methods, why else would have they proveided the toString() method if we couldn't convert char array into String??

Comment: As I indicated in [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798066/gettext-vs-getpassword/9798110#comment12481480_9798110) you bypass the whole security mechanism by using "s123". Better would be to compare char arrays

Answer (score 3):

Note: this should have been a comment but is way too long for this. Consider giving the upvotes to the answers in the linked thread

As already indicated by mKorbel there is a rather complete discussion in [getText() vs getPassword()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798066/gettext-vs-getpassword) .

Further, read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) about `JPasswordField` which contains a nice example on how you should compare the password (by comparing char arrays, and not by converting the char array to a `String`) - small copy paste from the tutorial:

```
private static boolean isPasswordCorrect(char[] input) {
    boolean isCorrect = true;
    char[] correctPassword = { 'b', 'u', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'o', 'o' };

    if (input.length != correctPassword.length) {
        isCorrect = false;
    } else {
        isCorrect = Arrays.equals (input, correctPassword);
    }

    //Zero out the password.
    Arrays.fill(correctPassword,'0');

    return isCorrect;
}
```

The reason why you should compare char arrays is nicely explained by [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798093/1076463) in the linked SO question at the start of this answer.

Comment: i was planning previously to implement this function, but i thought for saving few lines of code we can use the toString() method, and it works as told by Johannes

Comment: @lucifer Using `toString` makes a String which ends up in the StringPool, bypassing all the security measures taken in the `JPasswordField`. So yes, it works but it is incorrect

Comment: actually i am comparatively new to java, what is StringPool?
in which part of java will i learn such concepts? because i am using Sun Core java Fundamentals and Deital and Deital java how to program, the only part they have given in the core java version of these books is the basic things excluding all the details of JVM, StringPool or the security features, although they had noted that when you take the password delete the character array for security concernn
in which book will i get these deep understanding of java?

Comment: i read few things  in [http://google-interview.com/] about a Java interview but didnt understand even though i am good at core java, these interviews posted went over my head....
i felt bad after that!
is language proficiency needed in one language or in one Paradigm?

Comment: @lucifer not sure which books would describe this. But a quick search on this site for string pool should give you enough information (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them)

Comment: yeah the quick search is done provided i know in the first place what the thing means!!
in no book did i find such concepts!! where will i find them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    char[] pass = passwordField.getPassword();
    String mypass = pass.toString();
    String user = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();


    try {
        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        String db = "jdbc:odbc:LoginDB";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from Table2";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {

            String AdminNewID = rs.getString("AdminID");
            String AdminNewPass = rs.getString("AdminPassword");

            if ((user.equals(AdminNewID)) && pass.equals(AdminNewPass)) {

                MyApp form = new MyApp();
                form.setVisible(true);

            } else {
                this.res.setText(" Incorrect User Name or Password");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not store passwords in plain text. Please do no swallow exceptions. Please use conventional naming.

Comment: you ought to try this:

`new String(txtPwd.getPassword()).equals("YourPassword")`

instead of creating what you did
`char[] pass = passwordField.getPassword();
    String mypass = pass.toString();`

This will be better than creating a char array object and also creating a string object