# JPasswordField encoding the input

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

Java's `JPasswordField` is encoding the input which user enter in password field and I don't want it. I am checking password against database values which are purely numeric values.

Am entering the numeric values for password as

```
12345
```

and it returns

```
[C@1e9b48b
```

Comment: What do you mean by encoding? You should just be able to use the `getPassword` method.

Comment: Really?! How did you get that to work?!

Comment: Are you misinterpreting the `char[]` typically returned, for a `String`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson According to the JavaDoc's it's a `char[]` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword()  Which method are you referring to?

Comment: it's actually returning a char[] and it's not encoded. Maybe it's encoded in the database (with MD5?)

Comment: @Austin  My bad.  I suffer [CRAFT syndrome](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Craft%20syndrome).  A great case for 'RTFM' before 'open mouth'. ;)

Comment: Take a look at this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html

Comment: m entering the numeric values for password as 12345 and it returns [C@1e9b48b

Comment: It seems you are printing the Array itself.  That will not work.

Comment: Yep you're doing what I suspected, my answer shows you how to fix that. and @AndrewThompson I had to google that, nice :p

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9894112/1076463) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9798066/1076463)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think when you mean encoding, you're probably trying to use the `toString` method. Which on a char array, will just use the standard object `toString` method.

Instead you could probably do

```
String password = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
```

The only other way it's "encoded" is if you're getting an encrypted password somehow.

Comment: +1, though note that passwords are typically not returned as `String` instances for very a good security related reason.  I am not sure what that reason is, but it has probably been asked/answered many times before.

Comment: @user1734885 If it worked, you're welcome to press the checkmark button to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Converting the `char[]` to a `String` is of course an answer to this question, but it is not the recommended way for dealing with passwords. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9798093/1076463) on a related question

Comment: @AndrewThompson The reason is so that you can null out the array after use. You can't do that with a String so it remains lying around, readable from e.g. the swap file.

Answer (score -1):

The doc come with a sample http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html

The input is not 'encoded' but for each character you enter a special character is printed in the inout field.