# How to set variables into a JDBC statement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

It works when i try to insert variables for example :

```
String insertStr="INSERT INTO  table1(username1,password1) VALUES(\"john\",\"password\")";
```

but unable to insert using variable

```
String a=username.getText();
String b=password.getText();

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_db1","root","");  

    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();        
    String insertStr="INSERT INTO  table1(username1,password1) VALUES(a,b);";
    stmt.executeUpdate(insertStr);
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Comment: String insertStr="INSERT INTO  table1(username1,password1) VALUES("+strA+","+strB+");";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`PreparedStatement`][1] instead of your way, because your way can be a victim of SQL Injection or Syntax errors :

```
String insertStr = "INSERT INTO  table1(username1,password1) VALUES(?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(insertStr)) {
    pst.setString(1, a);
    pst.setString(2, b);
    pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

For reason of security I don't suggest to get password with `getText()`, instead use `getPassword()`, so you can use :

```
pst.setString(1, username.getText());
pst.setString(2, new String(passwordField.getPassword()));
```

Take a look at this :

- [getText() vs getPassword()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798066/gettext-vs-getpassword)
- [Why getText() in JPasswordField was deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443308/why-gettext-in-jpasswordfield-was-deprecated)
  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: There's a small syntax error on line 2, the colon shouldn't be there on the try with resources. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment @joshpetit, what did you mean I don't get you.

Comment: there's a *semi-colon here: `try (PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(insertStr);)` after insertStr.

Comment: Also this is likely a separate post, but is there a way to use the same variable for multiple fields? I.e use the same variable for both question marks in the prepared statement?

Comment: @joshpetit Yes it is unnecessary semicolon, you can edit my question to let your trace behind :) and about your question, yes you can use `pst.setString(1, sameThing); pst.setString(2, sameThing);`

Comment: ok I see that, I was wondering if it would be possible to do that but without calling it multiple times, but I can just do a loop, all works the same!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inserting "a" and "b" as String, not their variable values.

```
String insertStr="INSERT INTO  table1(username1,password1) VALUES("+a+","+b+");";
```

should do it, but I would recommend to use a prepared statement here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: You shouldn't use variable directly in a SQL String as this as this is vulnerable to DB Injection attack.

Comment: @TravisStevens That's why I recommended prepared statements...

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to insert variable values into sql is to use the [PreparedStatement Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

With this object, you can add variable values into a SQL Query without fearing of SQL injection. 
Here an example of **PreparedStatement** :

```
//[Connection initialized before]
String insertStr="INSERT INTO  table1(username1,password1) VALUES(?,?);";
PreparedStatement myInsert = myConnectionVariable.prepareStatement(insertStr); // Your db will prepare this sql query
myInsert.setString(1, a); //depending on type you want to insert , you have to specify the position of your argument inserted (starting at 1)
myInsert.setString(2, b); // Here we set the 2nd '?' with your String b
myInsert.executeUpdate(); // It will returns the number of affected row (Works for UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE,etc...)
//You can use executeQuery() function of PreparedStatement for your SELECT queries
```

This is safer than using String concatenation like this : `VALUES("+a+","+b+");`

Take a look at Java Doc for more information ;)